# app crash while loading large amount of items to listbox

Tags: c#, image, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am developing a **windows phone8 app**
I have a ListBox which shows large number of items, I have a image control too inside that data template of ListBox.

When I load first 100 items its working well, when I load next 100 items(totally 200) app crash happens.

Can anybody help me to solve this issue.

Here my code for list box

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Visibility="Visible" x:Name="commentsListBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border BorderBrush="#FFB9B9B9" BorderThickness="0,0,0,2" Width="462" Margin="14,0,0,0">
                                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="470" >
                                    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,20,0,0" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding profileImage}"></Image>
                                    <TextBlock Name="userNameTextBlock"  VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding userName}" Foreground="Black" Height="36" Width="238" Margin="136,18,0,0" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" FontFamily="Tahoma" />
                                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="146,68,0,0" Width="314">
                                        <TextBlock Name="commentTextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextAlignment="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding comment}" Width="313" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontFamily="Tahoma" Margin="0,0,-17,0" ></TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding date}" Height="36" Foreground="Red" Width="264"  Name="commentDate" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,10,0" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" FontFamily="Tahoma"></TextBlock>
                                        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="100" Content="View" Height="70" FontSize="18" x:Name="viewBtn" Background="#FFD71D26" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,-10,-10"></Button>
                                    </StackPanel>

                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <!--<ListBoxItem>

            </ListBoxItem>-->
                </ListBox>
```

and the class which have the data is

```
 public class WishListCommentCommonFormate
{
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public string profileImage { get; set; }
}
```

here the image is given as URL from a website.
I saw the [Improving ListBox Performance in Silverlight for Windows Phone 7: Data Virtualization](http://shawnoster.com/2010/08/improving-listbox-performance-in-silverlight-for-windows-phone-7-data-virtualization/) and few more examples like that, but i couldn't got the idea to fix this issue.

Please give me some idea.
Thank you.

Comment: You are running out of memory. You need to use less RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions. The first if you MUST use a ListBox you'll have better performance and virtualization of your images by reading [ListBox why art thou blanking](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/05/16/listbox-why-art-thou-blanking.aspx). In this article from the Windows Phone development team they mention a different way to set images.

```
<Image> 
    <Image.Source> 
        <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding ImgUrl}" CreateOptions="BackgroundCreation"/> 
    </Image.Source> 
</Image>
```

The second suggestion (and probably the better) is to not use the LstBox but instead use the [LongListSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.longlistselector%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). This control was made to be performant, and to use less memory. Simply do a Find/Replace from ListBox to LongListSelector in your xaml.

Comment: Hi thanks your reply, I will try LongListSelector and will update the response.